# Python 3.x Segmentation Fault with Threading module

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, python-multithreading

Machine: Raspberry Pi 3B+ 
System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Python version: Python 3.7.3

I have created code, that downloads chapters for novel from internet site protected by Cloudflare. Since downloading 400 sites with 5 seconds delay each time took over 1.5 hour i rewrote the code to use it with threading module.
It was a success. With 4 threads i managed to take it down to 16 minutes.

But from time to time Segmentation Fault occured. Also, when i increased thread count, it occured more often/sooner in the progress(of download) and with 6 it was almost certain, that it will occur.

First thing i tried to do(which i found somewhere on Raspberry Pi forums) was to increase stack size with `ulimit -s (stack size)`. It didn't help. I had a feeling, that it increased how often it occured.

After that i found `faulthandler` module [here](https://blog.richard.do/2018/03/18/how-to-debug-segmentation-fault-in-python/). I enabled it with

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
PYTHONFAULTHANDLER = 1
```

and it gave me this once fault occured (core is function defined in the script):

```
    Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x6f6ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 89 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x700ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1914 in do_handshake
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 453 in wrap_socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344 in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344 in connect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841 in _validate_conn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343 in _make_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600 in urlopen
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449 in send
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646 in send
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 121 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546 in get
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 49 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x70aff460 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 287 in feed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 342 in _feed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 281 in __init__
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 50 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x714ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 773 in load_verify_locations
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 428 in load_verify_locations
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 321 in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344 in connect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841 in _validate_conn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343 in _make_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600 in urlopen
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449 in send
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646 in send
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 121 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 219 in solve_cf_challenge
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 129 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546 in get
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 49 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x71eff460 (most recent call first):
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 253 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x728ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 415 in select
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1681 in _communicate
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 939 in communicate
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 322 in solve_challenge
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 204 in solve_cf_challenge
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 129 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 237 in solve_cf_challenge
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 129 in request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546 in get
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 49 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x7329c460 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 287 in feed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 342 in _feed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 281 in __init__
  File "new Tensura download.py", line 50 in core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x76fe5ad0 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1048 in _wait_for_tstate_lock
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1032 in join
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1281 in _shutdown
bash: linia 1: 18565 Naruszenie ochrony pamięci   /usr/bin/python3 "new Tensura download.py"
```

I see, that the fault is caused by threading module, but i have no idea how to fix it.
If you have any clue, on how to eliminate this, i will be thankful.

Here is the whole code if somebody wants it the threading initiator is at the very end (note, that **enscript** and **ps2pdf** terminal programs are required to run core and **cfscrape** module is request module for Cloudflare protected websites):

```
#improvment from 1h 40min to 1h 10 min with new version
#with 2 threads this goes down to 36 min
#with 4 down to 16 min (if i remember correctly)
#with 5 down to 13 min 40 s
#with 6 down to 13 min (segmentation faults occur)

#handling segmentation fault
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
PYTHONFAULTHANDLER = 1

import cfscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading
import subprocess
from time import time

#------time tracking class------
class time_check():
    def __init__(self):      #starts time tracking
        self.start_t = time()
    def check(self):         #prints current time from start
        end_t = time()
        t = end_t - self.start_t
        
        t_sec = int(t % 60)
        t_min = int(((t - t_sec) / 60) % 60)
        t_hr = int(((((t - t % 60) / 60) - t_min) / 60) % 24)
        
        print(f'Operation took {t_hr} hours {t_min} minuts {t_sec} seconds.')

#----------------------------creating scraper------------------------
print('scrape s')
scrape = cfscrape.create_scraper()
source = scrape.get('https://www.readlightnovel.org/tensei-shitara-slime-datta-ken-wn', headers={"User-Agent": "XZ"}).content
print('scrape e')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#---------------------char table-----------------------------
                  #   V    Vnbsp-V would you believe? there are more than 1 type of spaces. one is 160(noble space), other 32 in hex, another 12288
chars = ['\t', '\n', '\r', ' ', ' ', '　', '', '「', '“', '」', '”', '『', '』'] #         VV VV these are not the same markers
for x in '''QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm-_=+,＜<《〈≪.≫〉》>＞[{]};:'"/?`‘’~1234567890!！@#$%^&*＊※()\|…–—−ー・→°✦✧''':
    chars.append(x)

#-----------------------getting more links from main site------------------------------------
print('link s')
links, link = [], []
table = soup.find_all('ul', class_='chapter-chs')[:4]
for x in table:
    x = x.find_all('a')
    links += x
    
for x in links:
    link += [x['href']]
print('link e')

#--------------------core------------------------------
#purely esthetic purpose, brerak lines, changes characters, nicely breaks lines and saves it to files
def core(links, thr_id='?'):
    ttime = time_check()
    for num, link in enumerate(links):
        
        #--------------------------request--------------------------------
        source = scrape.get(link, headers={"User-Agent": "XZ"}).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        
        
        #---------------------some deleting of useless data---------------------------
        for trin in soup.find_all('div', class_='trinity-player-iframe-wrapper'):
            trin.replace_with('')
        for scr in soup.find_all('script'):
            scr.replace_with('')
        for scr in soup.find_all('text-center add11'):
            scr.replace_with('')
        for scr in soup.find_all('text-center'):
            scr.replace_with('')
        for div in soup.find_all('div', 'hidden'):
            div.replace_with('')
        
        #----------getting title for chapter---------------------------
        try:
            title = soup.find('div', class_='block-title').h1.text
        except:
            try:
                title = f'v6 Tensei Shitara Slime Datta Ken (WN) - Chapter {num.name}'
            except:
                title = f'v6 Tensei Shitara Slime Datta Ken (WN) - Chapter {num}'
        
        #-------------------getting wanted part of the site--------------------
        desc = soup.find('div', class_='desc').text
        
        #----------------new line/dialogue breaker------------------------------
        beg_list, end_list, tetr, out = ['「', '(', '<', '“', '＜', '《', '≪'], ['」', ')', '>', '”', '》', '≫'], '   ', ''
        dialog = 0 
        
        #it is based on cart/sight/focus basically there is this tetr variable.
        #At the beginning it changes its focus from lets say characters 21,22,23 to 22,23,24, and at the end addes first one to the output(in this case it would add 22).

        #thats only if nothing would be changed.
        #But each time newest letter (24 for this example) is added, it goes through a scanner.
        
        #Some(all) of them manually alter the focus, so that new letters can be added(mostly \n).
        for x in desc:
            tetr = tetr[1:] + x
                        
            if tetr in [' . ', ' . ', '　.　'] and dialog == 0:     #line end after dot v1
                tetr = ' \n '
                out += '.'
            
            elif tetr[1:] in ['. ', '. ', '.　'] and dialog == 0:   #line end after dot v2
                out += tetr[0]
                tetr = tetr[0] + '.\n'
            
            elif x in beg_list and dialog == 0:     #beginning of dialog/thought or something similar
                dialog = 1
                out += tetr[0:2]
                tetr = tetr[2] + '\n' + x
                
            elif x in end_list:                           #end of above
                dialog = 0
                out += tetr[0:2]
                tetr = tetr[2] + x + '\n'
            
            elif x in ['!', '！', '?'] and dialog == 0:        #breaker for ! and ?
                out += tetr[0:2]
                tetr = tetr[1] + x + '\n'
            
            else:                                       #for all other letters
                out += tetr[0]
                
        desc = out
        del out, beg_list, end_list, tetr, dialog
        
        #------------------character changer------------------------
        out, tetr = '', '   '
        for x in desc:
            tetr = tetr[1:] + x
            
            
            if tetr[0] not in chars:
                out += '\\'
                continue
            
            if tetr[0] in ['△'] :
                out += '$'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['’', '‘'] :
                out += "'"
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['「'] :
                out += '['
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['」'] :
                out += ']'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['＞', '〉'] :
                out += '>'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['＜', '〈'] :
                out += '<'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['“', '”'] :
                out += '"'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['＊'] :
                out += '*'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['※']:
                out += '--'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['…'] :
                out += '...'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['『', '“', '《', '≪', '〈'] :
                out += '<<'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['』', '”', '》', '≫', '〉'] :
                out += '>>'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['–', '—', 'ー', '・', '−'] :
                out += '-'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['→'] :
                out += '->'
                
            elif tetr[0] in [' ', '　']:
                out += ' '
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['\t']:
                out += '    '
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['！']:
                out += '!'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['é']:
                out += 'e'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['Ō']:
                out += 'Oo'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['✦', '✧']:
                out += '*'
                
            elif tetr[0] in ['°']:
                out += ' degrees '
            
            else:
                out += tetr[0]
             
        desc = out
        del out, tetr
        
        #--------------------nice line break---------------------------------
        line, f_list = '', []
        for x in desc:            #converting long text into list of shorter strings
            if x == '\n':
                f_list.append(line)
                line = ''
            line += x
        
        for y, line in enumerate(f_list):
            if len(line) > 91:
                for z in range(91, -1, -1):
                    v = line[z]
                    if v in [' ', ' ']:              #looking for closest space from the (length) character to first
                        sep = z    #+1          #separator
                        break
                else:                       #or taking the (width) bit
                    sep = 90
                    
                if sep == 0:
                    sep = 1
                    
                part1 = line[:sep]   #separating line
                part2 = line[sep:]
                f_list[y] = part1 + '\n'      #and adding it to menu  (part1 to place on old line)
                f_list.insert(y+1, part2)                   #(part 2 to next line)
        
        out = ''
        for line in f_list:
            out += line
            
        desc = out
        del out, sep, part1, part2, f_list, line
        
        #-------------title adder------------------
        desc = title + '\n' + desc
        
        #----------------file creator------------------------
        file = f'v7 {title}'
        with open(f'v7/{file}.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(desc)
        file = f'v7 {title}'
        
        #----------------------------ps creeation--------------------------
        n_file_ps = f'{file}.ps'
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['enscript', '-p', f'psv7/{n_file_ps}', f'v7/{file}.txt', f'--header={file}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        proc.wait()
        
        #---------------------------pdf creation----------------------------------
        n_file_pdf = f'{file}.pdf'
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['ps2pdf', f'psv7/{n_file_ps}', f'pdfv7/{n_file_pdf}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        proc.wait()
        
        print(thr_id, n_file_pdf, 'done')
        
    ttime.check()

#-----------------------------folders--------------------------------
try:       #deleing existing files
    proc = subprocess.Popen('cd pdfv7 && rm v7*', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
    proc = subprocess.Popen('cd psv7 && rm v7*', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
    proc = subprocess.Popen('cd v7 && rm v7*', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
except:
    pass

for fold in ['psv7', 'pdfv7', 'v7']:
    try:    #creating new folders
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', fold], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    except:
        pass
    proc.wait()

#---------------------threads creation------------------------------------------
#for fixing segmentation error i used terminal command(8192 default) "ulimit -s 16284" <---no, i changed it back
thr_times = 7          #6 sometimes throws up segmentation fault (like 5 but more often)(4 also does that, but more chaotically)

threads = {}
for x in range(thr_times):    #creating threads                                     #V V V splitting links equally for all of the threads
    threads[str(x)] = threading.Thread(target=core, name=f'Tensura thr.{x}', args=([link[x::thr_times], x])) #<-- x == thread id

for thread in threads:
    threads[thread].start()


# core([link[80]])
```

Edit:
Okay, since no one was answering i created my workaround.
If you can't capture segmentation fault within script just create another script that launches and monitors if script is running. Pretty neat huh?
Problem is if script is killed near the end, as it will have to start all over, but you can go away from keyboard and if Segmentation Fault is you only problem, this script will have the work done(unless something else happens).

```
import subprocess
import time
import psutil
from fnctime import time_check

def kill(proc_pid):
    process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
        proc.kill()
    process.kill()

ttime = time_check()

#begin process
p0 = subprocess.Popen('cd /home/pi/scripts/"Tensura Beautiful soup" && python3.7 "new Tensura download.py"', stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
#define variable for checking if p0 is alive
status = p0.poll()

try:
    while True:
        if status != None:          #if process is dead  start it again
            print('\nStart it again')
            p0 = subprocess.Popen('cd /home/pi/scripts/"Tensura Beautiful soup" && python3.7 "new Tensura download.py"', stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
            status = p0.poll()      #and renew status
            
        while status == None:                        #while it is alive
            print(p0.stdout if p0.stdout else '', end='')     #print what it has printed
            time.sleep(1)                    #wait
            status = p0.poll()              #check again
            
        a, b = p0.communicate()
        
        if b == 'Segmentation fault\n':        #if Segmentation fault occured: 
            print('--Segmentation fault--')
            continue                           #go again
        if 'UnicodeDecodeError' in b:
            print('Unicode Decode Error')
            continue
        print(f'--b: {b} --')
        print('--all done--')
        break                        #break whole loop
except KeyboardInterrupt:          #if ctrl^C was clicked
    try:
        kill(p0.pid)           #kill the process
    except:
        print('already dead')      #unless it's dead already

ttime.check()
```

I hope i helped in some way to live with this problem without solving it.

Comment: The good news: you’ve probably found a bug in Python, since it should be impossible to provoke a segmentation fault using only these libraries.  The bad news: it might be “just” a resource limitation, and you probably need to run a real debugger (*e.g.*, GDB) to find out what it is.

Comment: Okay, did that and got result. Each debugging starts with this, do you have any idea what to do? :
#0  0x75e45804 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so